# SQL Select all rows with specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to select all rows with the value `33487MO` in the column `ORMSTRID`

This is my current query -

```
SELECT * from MyTable
Where ORMSTRID = "33487MO"
```

But it gives me an error that is saying `Invalid column name '33487MO'`

```
SELECT * from MyTable
```

shows me all of the rows and columns from the table, and `ORMSTRID` is definitely the column name.

Comment: `single-quote` for `string`

Comment: God damnit... that'll do it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use single quote with string data
According your example your query should be:

```
select * from mytable
where ORMSTRID like '33487MO'
```

Comment: Missing clause `from`

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry I corrected it